# Ansible list variable undefined

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have a playbook which runs a custom task to set up an nginx vhost:

```
  tasks:
    - include: tasks/tweaks.yml
```

In this playbook, the following `var_files` are used:

```
  vars_files:
    - ../config.yml
```

In `config.yml` I have the following list which holds the vhost info:

```
nginx_hosts_custom:
  - server_name: "mytest.dev"
    root: /drupal/www/mytest
    is_php: true
    common_config: true
    remote_host: "12.34.56.78"
    remote_root: "/web/ubuntu/www/mytest/public"
    pem: "mytest.pem"
```

Within `tweaks.yml` I have the following:

```
- name: "Extra Nginx hosts for the Drupal sites"
  template:
    src: ../templates/nginx-vhost.conf.j2
    dest: "{{ nginx_vhost_path }}/{{ item.server_name.split(' ')[0] }}.conf"
    force: yes
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644
  with_items: nginx_hosts_custom
  notify: restart nginx
  when: drupalvm_webserver == 'nginx'
```

This used to work perfectly, but now I receive the following error when running the provision:

```
fatal: [owenvm]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'server_name'\n\nThe error appears to have been in /tasks/tweaks.yml': line 20, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: \"Extra Nginx hosts for the Drupal sites\"\n  ^ here\n"}
```

So it appears the variable `server_name` is not being picked up - can anyone suggest a fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bare variables in `with_items`, like `with_items: nginx_hosts_custom` are deprecated since Ansible 2.0 and are totally unsupported since 2.2.

You should use `with_items: "{{ nginx_hosts_custom }}"`

Answer (score 1):

In `tweaks.yml`

```
- name: "Extra Nginx hosts for the Drupal sites"
  template:
    src: ../templates/nginx-vhost.conf.j2
    dest: "{{ nginx_vhost_path }}/{{ item['server_name'].split(' ') | first }}.conf"
    force: yes
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644
  with_items: nginx_hosts_custom
  notify: restart nginx
  when: drupalvm_webserver == 'nginx'
```

Also, template usually knows to look in `../templates` (at least when using roles). Are you sure you need to give a relative path? Sticking to your template filename may be enough.

Depending on Ansible version, `with_items` may need to be set to `'{{ nginx_host_custom }}'`. Although according to your error message, this is not our case.

I'ld also recommend making sure `nginx_hosts_custom` is defined in your `when` clause, such as:

```
when: drupal_webserver == 'nginx' and nginx_hosts_custom is defined and nginx_hosts_custom != False
```